# How to pass two arguments while calling jar file in batch script?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar

Following is my batch script

```
@echo off

set /a java_output=43350674
set /a img_id=1

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:top

for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%A in ( 'java -jar test.jar %java_output%,%img_id%' ) do (
    set /a java_output=%%A
    set /a img_id=%%B
)

echo %java_output%
SET /A "err=error"
if "%java_output%" EQU "%err%" (
    echo %img_id% > batch_log.txt
    echo "End of batch script"
    exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
) else (
    if %java_output% LSS 43350681 ( 
        goto top 
    )
)
endlocal
```

Getting expected output but I am getting "Missing operand" error each time the for loops runs.

```
Error in " set /a img_id=%%B "
```

I have doubt in this line `for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%A in ( 'java -jar test.jar %java_output%,%img_id%' ) do (`

Is this the correct way to pass 2 batch variables to jar file ?

Following is my java code in jar file.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
       {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        int ret = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        // for error scenarios
        String err = "error";
        if(ret == 43350677)
        { 
            System.out.println(err+" "+ret);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(ret+1+" "+ret);
        }
       }
}
```

Following is my output :

```
C:>test.bat
Missing operand.
43350675
Missing operand.
43350676
Missing operand.
43350677
Missing operand.
0
"End of batch script"
```

Comment: What output do you receive from `'java -jar test.jar %...` ?

Comment: A Integer value and "Missing operand error" for the second argument

Comment: Perhaps `java` is interpreting the input as a single string. I'd replace the comma with a space,

Comment: Even for space I am getting the same error

Comment: Please share output from `java -jar test.jar %java_output%,%img_id%` (see  @Magoo's first comment).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a jar file together with parameters out of a Windows script use the following syntax:

```
call java -jar my-jar-file.jar parm1 parm2 ...
```

The call is essential, otherwise the parameters are ignored.